# Need help with formula for sales commissions

Tags: limits, graphing-functions, infinity

Need Function For:

If x = 0, then y = 10. If x = infinity, then y=3

What is y if x = 100,000? 1,000,000?

where x is the amount of the sale and y is the amount of the commission

I'm sure this exists elsewhere but my limited understanding of mathematics has made it hard for me to search properly.

Comment: There are many possible function. One is $y=7\cdot e^{-\alpha\cdot x}+3$, where $\alpha>0$ is an arbitrary parameter. See the plot of the function here: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+7*e%5E(-0.04*x)%2B3,+0%3Cx%3C150,+0%3Cy%3C12)

Comment: hmmm that seems unnecessarily complicated. isn't there a function with only 2 variables? 1 input and one output?

Comment: Note that $\alpha$ is a parameter-not a variable. If you follow the link you will see that I have set $\alpha$ equal to 0.04: $y=7\cdot e^{-0.04 \cdot x}+3$. But you can choose another value for the parameter if you want. I wanted to make it a bit more general.

Comment: $y=3+\frac{7}{x+1}$

Comment: My apologies, didn't see the link. Yes this works well. Thank you callculus

Comment: You are welcome. As I said there are many other types function with your requirements for instance the function of dromastyx in the comments.